# IE 9 Disabling of Script

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I every now and then accidentally click the Disable > Script option on the developer toolbar.  Is there a better way to undo that other than going into Tools > Internet Options to fix it?  It's very inconvenient for that to be the fix...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my scenario, it's actually a bug in IE not allowing me to click the toggle feature again, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It's a toggle option - the first time you select it, a check mark appears and script is disabled.  The next time you select it, the check mark disappears and script is enabled again.

So, to answer your question, just click *Disable* -> *Script* again and you will undo your action.

Comment: Yes, I've had that behavior working on a different computer - strangely enough, it's not toggling for me.  I had to go into internet options to fix it.  Must be a bug.